# can i optimize my code further - reduce for loop

Tags: python, algorithm

Can I optimize the code? Number can be from 1 to 10**9.

I want to print how many number of time each digit from 0 to 9 occur in book from pages 0 to N.

Can I use `map` instead of second for loop in this case?

for i in range (1,number+1):
        for dig in str(i):
            dic[dig] = dic[dig]+1

Comment: i am trying to get total accurances of each number of digit[0 to 9] for the numbers from 1 to N

Comment: Could you please explain further? What is the expected output?

Comment: i want to print how many number of time each digit from 0 to 9 occur in book from pages 0 to N...

Comment: I edited my answer. I think that's what you want

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want to add one to each value. You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dic = {k: v+1 for k, v in dic.items()} # Or dic.iteritems() in Python <2.7
```

After some clarification, looks like you're looking for:

```
for page in book:
    for n in range(1, 10):
        dic[str(n)] += page.count(str(n))
```

Comment: Looks like there is a change in question. Check OP's comment in question.

Comment: Is a dictionary really faster than a list for this problem?  Or str(c) faster than ord(c)-ord('0') if c is known to be a digit?  (Not doubting--just curious.  I've seen all sorts of "counter-intuitive" timings from interpreters.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
def solve(N):
   return sum((Counter(str(i)) for i in xrange(1, N+1)), Counter())

print solve(10)
print solve(100)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'1': 2, '0': 1, '3': 1, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 1, '7': 1, '6': 1, '9': 1, '8': 1})
Counter({'1': 21, '3': 20, '2': 20, '5': 20, '4': 20, '7': 20, '6': 20, '9': 20, '8': 20, '0': 11})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like this

```
number = 100
from collections import Counter
print Counter("".join([str(i) for i in range (1, number+1)]))
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'1': 21, '3': 20, '2': 20, '5': 20, '4': 20, '7': 20, '6': 20, '9': 20, '8': 20, '0': 11})
```

**Edit:** As hcwhsa suggested in the comment, your solution is already the best. If reducing the number of lines is your goal, without importing anything, you can use this

```
number = 100
numString = "".join([str(i) for i in range (1, number+1)])
print {str(i):numString.count(str(i)) for i in range(10)}
```

Comment: @user2991556 If you can't import anything then your solution is okay, but If you want to improve from `O(N)` then you'll have to use some mathematical trick.

Comment: @user2991556 Nothing I can think off the top of my head, but I've added the `algorithm` tag to your question, that may help.

Comment: @user2991556 Please check my answer now. But, as hcwhsa said, your solution is already the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have time to time or test this, but my old-school approach would be something like:

```
digits = "0123456789"
counts = [0] * (len(digits) + 1)
for c in text:
    counts[digits.find(c)] += 1
```

That works for any set of characters, not just digits, and the extra position in the counts list will count non-matching characters. (.find() returns -1 on a char not found, so the index is ready-made to pick the last list entry.)

Answer (score 0):

There is far more efficient solution for this question if you only want to know how many times each digits (0 - 9) appear in number [1, N]. Brute force iteration is not neceesary.